# javaScript switch cases with a number rang 1-5

Tags: javascript, html

Can I make a switch case that looks for a number in between a certain range? like 1-4 example:

```
 switch(3.43) {
      case '1,2,3,4,5' :
      console.log('its 3.43!')
      break;    
      case '6-10' :
      console.log('its not 3!')
      break;  
  }
```

Comment: switch case is the wrong solution for ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a normal `if` statement:

```
var num = 3.43;
if (1 <= num && num <= 5) {
    console.log("Yay!");
} else if (6 <= num && num <= 10) {
    console.log("Aww.");
}
```

`switch` statements only allow for specific cases. It's possible to do ranges, but it's a bit hacky.

Answer (score 3):

Use if else

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkNumber () {
var n = //get value
var entered = "You entered a number between"; 

if (n >= 1 && n < 10)                   
  {alert(entered + " 0 and 10")}
else if (n >= 10 && n < 20)
  {alert(entered + " 9 and 20")}
else if (n >= 20 && n < 30)
  {alert(entered + " 19 and 30")}
else if (n >= 30 && n < 40)
  {alert(entered + " 29 and 40")}
else if (n >= 40 && n <= 100)
  {alert(entered + " 39 and 100")}
else if (n < 1 || n > 100)
  {alert("You entered a number less than 1 or greater than 100")}
else
  {alert("You did not enter a number!")}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> The program first looks for a case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the input expression (using strict comparison, ===) and then transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements. If no matching case clause is found, the program looks for the optional default clause...